# What to do when new user is rolling back valid edits

Tags: discussion, edits

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19035090/revisions). This user is rolling back valid edits to his question what can i do?

Comment: Flag for moderator intervention,  if they agree they'll lock the post

Comment: What especially bothers me is that a *mod's* edit was rolled-back.

Comment: @Jamal Yeah. That is my main suprise

Comment: My hunch is that some new users seem "confident" that their posts are great the way they are.  Here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18878999/revisions).

Comment: Three automatic rollback war flags on *one* post? o.o

Comment: @animuson The user refuses to be educated

Comment: That's a bit harsh @PreciousTijesunimi, the OP is brand new and until Bart stepped in no one had bothered to post a comment explaining why the rollbacks were inappropriate.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for locking that post

Comment: @Yannis Even after I and Bart posted comments, he still rolled back bart's edit

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Hm, hadn't notice that, you're right, this one seems to be a bit stubborn...

Comment: Though that more or less coincided with the posting of my comment @PreciousTijesunimi.

Comment: @animuson Will the OP even be able to respond to your comment?

Comment: @Bart Ha, clarified the last sentence. :) Though, can a new user flag their own post?

Comment: We'll know once he screams bloody murder after an hour @animuson ...

Comment: He's probably admiring his shiny Cleanup badge now.

Comment: Never ever heard of the phrase "edit war" until now...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do *not* start an edit war. Post a comment with short description and link to Help Center or meta question. If that does not help, flag for moderator's attention.

Comment: The user already rolledback a moderator's edit

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi so flag again, moderators are not notified about their edits rolled back, as far as I know.

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Comment and flag then (actually, don't comment, Bart already [took care of that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035090/emgucv-body-detection-using-haarcascade#comment28130360_19035090))

Comment: As much as it annoys me let a post stay with a bad rollback, you're right.  Edit wars just make things worse.

Comment: Yeah, [I'm having the same exact problem](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/497/communitys-view-on-old-question-grammar-edits/507#comment1821_507). I followed your advice and [posted a comment about it](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/923/how-do-i-know-when-current-sets-will-retire#comment17947_923) but I'm not really sure it's going to help. Another 5k+ user has participated in the war as well, which is very strange.

Answer (score 5):

Leave a message to the post telling the user to stop rolling back with a link to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you still see the user undoing your edits, then flag it for moderator attention.